# no Hadoop streaming jar

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-streaming

I have successfully installed hadoop3.3.0 and python2.7.16 on my mac OS. When I running:

```
python3 MRJob.py -r hadoop hdfs:///tt.txt -o hdfs:///output
```

It says:

> Exception: no Hadoop streaming jar

Can someone help me

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then check the [help/on-topic] to see what questions you can ask.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).

Comment: hadoop does not work like that. the code is not working like this and instead do as follow: `mapred streaming jar -files /file_directory_of_mapper_and_reducer -input /input -output /output -mapper “python3 mapper.py” -reducer “python3 reducer.py”`